# SQLAlchemy - "Optional" Foreign Key / Zero-to-One relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to switch from raw SQL to SQLAlchemy and I am struggling modelling a relationship between users and teams.
In this situation, a **team has a list of users** and a **user can be in zero or one team**.

Somethin like a "optional foreign key" in the table User, referencing to team.id could work, but it would have to be nullable which is not the best manner.

When using raw SQL, I usually create a third table **TeamUser(user_id, team_id)** with **user_id as primary key**.

It is entirely possible to replicate this in SQLAlchemy by creating a table, but the python code that need to be written to use those objects becomes less clear.

For example :

add a user to a team :

```
db.session.add(TeamUser(user_id=user.id, team_id=team.id)) 
#instead of
team.users.append(user)
```

access the team of a user:

```
user.team.team (user.team is now the couple (user_id, team_id))
```

get the list of users as User objects:

```
map(lambda team_user: team_user.user, team.users)  
#instead of
team.users
```

So my question is : is there a way to both model this user/team situation and keep an easy syntax while using SQLAlchemy objects?

I have looked at primary join but it doesn't seem to answer this problem. (but maybe I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a join table, take a look at [association_proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html).

For a one to many relationship, a foreign key is simpler. The player (user is likely a reserved word) has a reference to a team:

```
class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('team.id'))
    team = relationship('Team')
```

And a team has a list of players:

```
class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    players = relationship('Player', back_populates='team')
```

Then you can add a player via

```
team.players.append(player) # Player() object
```

Get a player's team (may be `None`)

```
team: Team = player.team
```

Get the list of players as Player objects

```
team.players
```

Comment: This answer addresses one-to-many, not zero-to-many.